# Can you use LXC through C?

Tags: c, programming, lxc, header-file

I want to use LXC to 'container' plugins my application is loading. Am I able to do this through C? I have been Googling a lot about it, but there don't seem to be any headers, only scripts that can be called through the terminal.

I know I can execute the scripts inside C, but I'd rather use the headers if there are any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the LXC homepage, you'll notice `liblxc` referred to, implying there's an ABI, and if you look further down, you'll notice a link to [the C API documentation](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/documentation/).

That page looks empty at first because it has been done (rather lazily, I think) with [doxygen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen).  However, if you start clicking around you'll find stuff.  Just keep in mind, again, that it's auto-generated from source and perhaps not a huge effort was put into annotating that in a doxygen friendly way.  Another perhaps confusing thing is all the actual functions are documented via function pointers in data structures (looks like an OO-ish interface).

But if you already know how to use LXC on the command line you should be able to deduce some correlations.